# Create a loop in a Linux filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

How do I create a loop in the Linux filesystem?  I want to break the directed acyclic graph (DAG) property of the Linux filesystem.  Is this possible?  I have seen this condition once when I installed the scratchbox cross compiler on my Ubuntu.

I don't know how to reproduce it now.

Comment: my interpretation of this question is different than what everyone seems to be answering... I'm thinking the OP wants an infinitely recursive directory structure.  This is possible to create using hardlinks, and maybe symlinks, but idk how to do it with mount, so I'll refrain from answering.

Comment: You can't hardlink directories in a "traditional" UNIX filesystem.

Comment: Scratchbox shouldn't create filesystem loops -- it shouldn't be able to, and I've used sb without anything like that happening.  Can you give more details on what happened?

Comment: there was loop in a filesystem when i installed scratch box in ubuntu feisty 7.04... when i ran updatedb i deteced a loop in the filesystem....

Comment: I want reproduce such sceanario now... dunno how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some other responders have already answered how to set up a mount using the loopback device, but you specifically asked about `bind` mounts, which are a little bit different.  If you want to use a bind mount, you just specify `--bind` in the mount command.  For example:

```
mount --bind /original/path /new/path
```

This will make the filesystem location accessible at `/original/path` *also* accessible through `/new/path`.  Note that this will *not* following mountpoints!  For example, suppose I have the following mountpoints:

```
/something
/something/underneath/that
```

Now suppose I make a `bind` mount for `/something`:

```
mount --bind /something /new_something
```

I will be able to access files like `/something/myfile` via the path `/new_something/myfile`.  But I will *not* be able to access files like `/something/underneath/that/otherfile` via the path `/new_something/underneath/that/otherfile`.  You must set up a separate `bind` mount for each filesystem; or if you have a relatively new kernel, you can use `rbind` mounts, which *do* follow mountpoints:

```
mount --rbind /something /new_something
```

One caveat about `rbind` mounts:  they do not handle the case where a filesystem is mounted after the `rbind` is setup.  That is, suppose I have a mount like this:

```
/something
```

Then I set up my `rbind` as above, and *then* I mount `/something/underneath/that`:  the `rbind` will not magically make the new mount visible through the `rbind` location.  Also be aware that apparently due to a bug in the kernel, you cannot unmount an `rbind` mount.

Also, just in case you meant "How do I set up bind mounts using the mount(2) system call?":  you must specify the `MS_BIND` flag (defined in `mount.h`) when you call `mount(2)` for a regular `bind` mount.  For an `rbind` mount, you must specify `MS_BIND` and the undocument `MS_REC` flag (defined in `linux/fs.h`).

Hope that helps,

Eric Melski

Answer (score 3):

It looks like all the answers so far are about mounting on loopback devices, and not creating a loop using [bind mounts](http://aplawrence.com/Linux/mount_bind.html).

As you've probably discovered,

```
$ mkdir -p test/test
$ mount --bind test test/test
```

only allows you to access `test/test/test`, and no further.  Not even

```
$ mount --rbind test test/test
```

works, because the recursive bind-mount effectively goes through finding existing mounts on the source and binding them in the target.

What you've asked for isn't possible, since bind mounts don't cross mount points.  If you really wish to simulate a filesystem loop, try use a pseudo-bind mount like [localfs](http://freesoft.portonvictor.org/virtual-filesystems.xml).  I haven't tried myself, it may lock up when trying to read a filesystem provided by itself.  Just now, I tried exporting a NFS tree with `crossmnt` and mounting it under itself, but fails for similar reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an *actual* answer for what you wanted:

If you want to actually create a real directory hard link, you can

### use debugfs

to manually edit the file system, and add a directory link. Like so:

```
# debugfs -w /dev/sda1 # For the first partition of the first SCSI disk.
debugfs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
debugfs: ln /tmp/crashMe /
```

This makes `/tmp/crashMe` point back to the root dir, and may crash your system, if you enter it at any time. So don’t forget to undo it later.

---

Alternatively, I found

### a passthrough/mirror file system.

to do the job nicely.
There are several FUSE implementations of this, as it is trivial. Searching for it, turned up at least five different ones on the first page, so I’ll avoid picking one. :)

Unlike with bind mounts AFAIK, the kernel does not seem to be able to prevent not such a file system from causing it trouble. In my tests, I could crash the kernel (a literal oops, requiring a reboot) with a mirror FUSE that I mounted as a *normal user*! Which is a major security problem, I think, but I may have forgotten that I allowed it in some kernel settings.

The point is: If you wanted to induce a crash or the like (esp. without messing a file system up or having the kernel stop you), I can testify that that this one gets you that. ;)

---

In general, the trouble with such loops is purely with the implementations of certain tools (and bits of the kernel, like permission checking I think, apparently), that traverse them. The file systems handle them just fine. IMHO it’s just bad programmers that can’t handle anything more complex than reference counting garbage collection. ;)

Answer (score -2):

```
mount /path/to/device /path/to/mount/location -o loop
```

where /path/to/device is the path to either the partition you want to mount, or the path to a disk image, and /path/to/mount/location is the path to the folder you want to mount the device/image under

you may also need to include the type of the file system like so (which uses fat16/fat32):

```
mount /path/to/device /path/to/mount/location -o loop -t vfat
```

Answer (score -2):

You may also want to create one from scratch:

First create the image file and initialize it

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/loop.img bs=1024k count=$IMG_SIZE
```

Next, make it a valid partition using an FS type of your choice

```
mkfs.ext3 -F /tmp/loop.img
```

Mount your new image

```
mkdir -p /mnt/image
mount /tmp/loop.img /mnt/image -o loop
```

You can now create/copy files and directories in your new image.